# Turbo crashes with any command in Official Node Docker image (Alpine)

Tags: turbo

Turbo crashes when using any command (e.g. `turbo build`), even when a valid project and `turbo.json` exists. This doesn't seem to be a problem on Ubuntu, but only on Alpine (arm64).

I've tried all of the new versions but they have the same issue.

- `npm install --global turbo`
- `npm install --global turbo@latest`
- `npm install --global turbo@canary`

### error:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to execute turbo.: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', crates/turborepo/src/main.rs:23:10
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because I was stuck on this for a few hours, I'll share solution here (which I also shared on [Github](https://github.com/vercel/turbo/issues/3373)):

- If using a Dockerfile: add `RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat` to it
- If using it on an Alpine machine, run `apk add --no-cache libc6-compat`

More explanation in:

- [Docker Node image docs](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine)

> - Alpine Linux is **much smaller** than most distribution base images (~5MB), and thus leads to much slimmer images in general.
> - The main caveat to note is that it does **use [musl libc](http://musl.libc.org/)** instead of **[glibc](http://www.etalabs.net/compare_libcs.html)** and friends, so certain software might run into issues depending on the depth of their libc requirements.
> - One common issue that may arise is a **missing shared library** ... . To add the missing shared libraries to your image, adding the libc6-compat package in your Dockerfile is recommended: `apk add --no-cache libc6-compat`

- https://github.com/vercel/turbo/issues/3373#issuecomment-1397080265