# Failed to execute turbo code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory"

Tags: reactjs, docker, dockerfile, turbo

I have had an issue the last few days, I hope I gonna resolve it with your help. I created a project with a turbo package When I want to build a docker file with the docker-compose file I got that error. Thank you

Error

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to execute turbo.: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: "No such file or directory" }', crates/turborepo/src/main.rs:50:10
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
error Command failed with exit code 101.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16.10.0-alpine3.11 AS builder
RUN apk update
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app

RUN yarn global add turbo@1.7.0
COPY . .

RUN turbo prune --scope=sport --docker

# Add lockfile and package.json's of isolated subworkspace
FROM node:16.16-alpine AS installer
RUN apk update

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /app/out/yarn.lock ./yarn.lock
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY turbo.json turbo.json

RUN yarn install

COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .

COPY /apps/sport/.env.dev .env
COPY /apps/sport/env.sh env.sh
COPY /apps/sport/entrypoint.sh entrypoint.sh
COPY /apps/sport/miniApp.json miniApp.json

RUN yarn turbo run build --filter=sport...
RUN ls -al
FROM node:16.16-alpine AS runner

RUN apk add --update --no-cache "bash=5.1.16-r2"
#RUN apk update && apk add bash

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=installer /app/apps/sport/build .
COPY --from=installer /app/entrypoint.sh .
COPY --from=installer /app/.env .
COPY --from=installer /app/env.sh .
COPY --from=installer /app/miniApp.json .

RUN chmod 755 env.sh
RUN chmod 755 entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/app/env.sh && /app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

I changed turbo version and node version and I added in dockerfile `RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat`but it is still same

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Turbo crashes with any command in Official Node Docker image (Alpine)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75174308/turbo-crashes-with-any-command-in-official-node-docker-image-alpine)

Answer (score 1):

I've stumbled upon exactly the same error which only occurs for the Dockerfile CMD part if it runs anything connected with turbo.

After spending almost 2 hours trying to fix it, had to end up using `concurrently` module as a temporary workaround for the app startup. Not the solution, but still.

Comment: Node 18.14.2-alpine, turbo 1.8.2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).